# Diagnosing Perplexing CSS errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, deployment

My website that has been up for a month now without any problems.

This morning everything was normal until I opened up the developer tools in chrome and when the cache refreshed the website was discombobulated!

Opening the website in Firefox I was able to get an idea of what is going on, but still have no clue how to resolve it.

**Opened the page in Firefox before refreshing the cache**

**Notice in the css log how there are no errors.**

[image]

**Refreshed the cache**

[image]

**None of the css is applied and as you can see lots of css related errors.**

I went through all my css/script files and none of them have been changed in the past 24 hours..  They all seem to be the same files that have been working perfectly for the past month.

Can anyone give me an idea of what might be going on here?  Is it a server issue?  Appreciate any ideas/answers to help me get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Does work all right in other browsers?

Comment: @PeterVasilev No this started happening in all browsers.  Before it was working as in looking like the first image in all browsers.

Comment: If you are using some kind of caching and/or minifying you should check those as they could be causing your problems

Comment: @PeterVasilev well I just tried using the non minified versions of my css/scripts but the problem still persists :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the solution ended up being non-programming related and the likely-hood of it being a help to anyone in the future is very low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

Another developer updated our bootstrap files from 2.3.2 to the latest version of bootstrap..  And for some reason the modified dates for the files did not change on the server.

Anyway because this issue is so isolated and the question probably won't be of any help to anyone in the future i'll remove it.. But leave this solution up for a few hours just as a FYI to those who have answered/commented on the question.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. BTW -moz-border-radius was dropped from Firefox 13. That's why you're seeing it as an error.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the arrow next to the CSS button in FF's browser tools and deselect warnings.

What you're seeing are warnings related to things like vendor related prefixes.

In general, if warnings are serious enough that action is required, they would be errors. In my opinion you can safely ignore them.

See here: [Should FF Error Console "Warnings" be taken seriously if page is not "broken"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806891/should-ff-error-console-warnings-be-taken-seriously-if-page-is-not-broken)

Comment: But my page is broken, look at the before/after pictures.

Comment: The warnings are for things like '-moz-border-radius' which should be parsed properly by Firefox obviously

Comment: Yes that's why its really odd.

Comment: I actually don't even know if this problem has started occurring yet from the outside.. But maybe you could check that for me.  If you go to http://www.wheelercat.com/jobs and apply for a job.  The application screen will come up.. It will either look normal like my first image or all messed up..  If I navigate there from my work computer then I will be on the internal server.. We have a different one hosting outside.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your site has lots the correct paths to the stylesheets. Have you changed your head or xml recently?